# SublimeCodeIntel isn't looking in python 3 paths

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimecodeintel

I installed SublimeCodeIntel package in sublime text, and I use it to code in python 3. However, the problem is that it uses python2 paths to do the import, so if a library is installed in python2 and not in python3, i won't find it when i use `import` or `from X import y`.

I did confirm that when I used the command `SublimeCodeIntel: Dump Import Directories` , so I saw both the files `python` and `python3` in the directory `./codeintel/import_dir_stats` and here is there content :

python

```
dedeeb56f744e507026fef17243da41f /home/bilal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
6a1d0cac3d9e6148e2208b63a33a1e6f /home/bilal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impacket
16a4fccbb3beadfdfd72691ef8f7298c /home/bilal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize
211d2b55059f6b634799fdae534decd9 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
be5448890caffe81686310f127d6efae /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_markerlib
cec69a0830a725e10ac4e364d44add8f /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appindicator
```

python3

```
dedeeb56f744e507026fef17243da41f /home/bilal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
6a1d0cac3d9e6148e2208b63a33a1e6f /home/bilal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/impacket
16a4fccbb3beadfdfd72691ef8f7298c /home/bilal/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize
211d2b55059f6b634799fdae534decd9 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
be5448890caffe81686310f127d6efae /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_markerlib
cec69a0830a725e10ac4e364d44add8f /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appindicator
```

I didn't put all the lines (because there is a lot), but the content of the two files is identical.

I don't understand from where is coming this problem, why SublimeCodeIntel is looking in python2 directories for the import ??!!

PS : I am using Ubuntu 15.10 (with Linux version > 4), and sublime text 3 build 3103.

Please help, I really consumed a lot of time and energy looking for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using the [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) plugin (no relation whatsoever to the Anaconda Python distribution) instead of SublimeCodeIntel. I struggled with SCI for a while on various machines, and could never get very good code completion out of it until I ran across Anaconda one day. The next day I removed SCI and have been completely satisfied ever since. It's super-easy to configure (just give it the path to your python executable and it reads `sys.path` and all the rest), and pretty much just works. It has linting with several different linters built-in (you can disable them if you want), has popups available for function signatures and other hints, works with virtualenvs right out of the box, and more.

(I didn't write it and I have no connection to the author(s) - it's just a great plugin!)

Comment: I did install anaconda, and couldn't get the popup for the function signatures. And does anaconda works with python3 too ??

Comment: I got it, i had to change the default python interpreter in the setting so it can show popups of python3 functions signatures (I tried with the print function).

Comment: @Sidahmed a good practice is to make a Sublime project for each project you're working on, then in the `.sublime-project` file add the Anaconda setting pointing to your interpreter of choice. Alternatively (like I do), you can make generic `Python 2` and `Python 3` projects, and open your individual programming projects in the appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks bro, you helped me a lot, anaconda is way better than sublimecodeintel. I know that I've asked a lot of questions here, but do you know any good plugin for autocompletion and showing tags attributs for html and css languages ??!! Thanks again bro.

Comment: @Sidahmed most people use [Emmet](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet) for writing HTML and CSS. Docs are [here](http://docs.emmet.io). To search for other plugins, just use Package Control's excellent [search function](https://packagecontrol.io/search).

Comment: In my case Anaconda linter never worked correctly. It could never find imports in a subdirectory. This is with Python3.